# SQL Execution order (HAVING befor SELECT)

Tags: mysql, sql

Everywhere where I looked I saw that `HAVING` is executed before `SELECT`, then why can I refer to the row `count` (that is created in the SELECT part) in the HAVING part?

```
SELECT `title`, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `comments` WHERE `post_id` = `posts`.`id`) as `count` FROM `posts` HAVING `count` != 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL has uniquely overloaded its `HAVING` operator such that it may be used similar to a `WHERE` clause, with the added functionality that it may refer to aliases defined at the same level of the query.  On other databases, your query would fail with a syntax error.  In that case, to get the same logic you would have to subquery to filter on the alias:

```sql
SELECT title, count
FROM
(
    SELECT title, (SELECT COUNT(*)
                   FROM comments
                   WHERE post_id = posts.id) AS count
    FROM posts
) t
WHERE count != 0;
```